# how to make SELECT tag selectable when outside of an active jquery dialog firefox

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

http://jsfiddle.net/7fu8rc0c/1/

I don't understand why if you can click the select tag, it does not show the options when the jquery ui dialog is active. Only modification is to css to remove overlay added by jquery ui.

```
.ui-widget-overlay {display:none;}
```

This sample is an extremely simplified version of an application which requires that a select tag be able to be modified outside of a potentially active jquery dialog (sometimes multiple dialogs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have "modal" set to true which is blocking the background page. Set Modal to false (or don't set it at all) and it should behave as expected.

Comment: shoot, in our implementation modal attribute is required, but in looking at the documentation, you are correct.